# Possible to add MIME type to web.config without possibly breaking the site?

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7

I had a web.config in one of the websites on my IIS that was adding a support for .7z file extension. When I later added a global .7z support at the server level, this site was broken - IIS Manager is complaining that it "cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'mimeMap'..." and all web requests to i.g. CSS files ended with an HTTP 500 error.

I was using this in the site's web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".7z" mimeType="application/x-7z-compressed" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Is there maybe some other syntax that would add 7z to the list only if it wasn't defined yet?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chaun/archive/2009/12/04/iis7-error-cannot-add-duplicate-collection-entry-of-type-mimemap-with-unique-key-attribute-fileextension.aspx), you should *remove* the global setting in the special config before adding it in a different form.

Explcitly:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".7z" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".7z" mimeType="application/x-7z-compressed" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Of course this doesn't really help you *now* as you might just as well drop the local setting completely (as it's likely to coincide with the global setting). But if you had known this back when you added local 7zip support, you wouldn't have encountered the error now ...

Comment: Was looking for this too long. Everything was OK online, but I didn't have "remove" before mimemap and localy site didn't load CSS. Upvoted, many thanks for this.

Comment: This works, because in some cases you have a higher .config file that already registered this mime type. In my case we had the mime type registered in some developers machines (at machine.config), but not in others, so to ensure that it will work for everyone, we remove and then add again.