# Download files in IIS as a zip file

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I just want to Download files from IIS folder.I can fetch all dynamic files by filling list in background via jquery it's done but then in controller side ,althought memoryStream find all files and adding zip archieves properly.I cannot download zip file with zipped files.WHY?

Thank you for helping...

```
public ActionResult SaveAllFiles(List<string> ImgPath) 
{ 
    if (ImgPath != null && ImgPath.Any())
    { 
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var ziparchive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < ImgPath.Count(); i++)
                {
                    string path = ImgPath[i].Substring(1).Replace("/", "\\");
                    string path2 = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + path;
                    ziparchive.CreateEntryFromFile(path2, path);
                }
            }                    
            return File(ms.ToArray(), "application/zip", "Attachments.zip");
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: What is going wrong? What is the error message?

Comment: Add zip mime type to IIS, and then download.

Comment: Actually,there is no error text but when I debug the code while CreateEntryFromFile inside of ziparchive.entries' threw an exception of type 'system.notsupportedexception'.As I said no exception its finishing with return file properly but non-downloaded file. @Bob

Comment: @Bosco I still did not push the commit.its on my local.When I merge it,I should make your changes I think so?

Comment: There are two ways to add the mime types in `Web.config` and in `IIS`. which ever you choose has its implications. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562580/possible-to-add-mime-type-to-web-config-without-possibly-breaking-the-site . You should be consistent with your changes both on local

Comment: @Bosco after your first reply I searched it and found [link](https://forums.iis.net/t/1193582.aspx) then tried it.Unfortunately return nothing with non-error still continues.

Comment: @UtkuYıldız is this ajax call ?

Comment: @satsvelke yes sir.

Comment: @UtkuYıldız then it will not work, as download file need full postback, try giving fullpost back

Comment: @UtkuYıldız see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AJAX(Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) is asynchronous, to download any file from server, the request must be synchronous, ajax does not supports file downloads

for work around see [this](http://johnculviner.com/jquery-file-download-plugin-for-ajax-like-feature-rich-file-downloads/) and [this](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload/blob/master/src/Scripts/jquery.fileDownload.js) , this will give "Ajax like" experience with file downloads

Comment: Thx man,after your answer, I changed my jquery and now its fine.

Comment: @UtkuYıldız It might be helpfull to others to post the code of your end result. ;-)

Comment: Hi dear @BobLokerse I changed my methodology from posting ImgPath list then redirect to new tab and posting Id.By this way, I'm checking ImgPath by Id then retrieve the paths and creating download file as zip.If you still ask the end result,I'll post it.