# How to add MIME type in headers

Tags: javascript, asp.net

My C# web application is working fine.

But due to security reasons, I need to use "nosniff" custom header in the web.config file.

```
 <system.webServer>
    </handlers>
      <httpProtocol>
          <customHeaders>
              <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
          </customHeaders>
      </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

Then it breaks the application and it shows nothing. I get following message in web browser:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://localhost:003/extnet-ini-js/ext.axd?' because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I am using extnet server based library.

It is a server based asp.net library I do not know how to add MIME type in headers? any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562580/possible-to-add-mime-type-to-web-config-without-possibly-breaking-the-site): Allow all Mime types that you need in your Backend app (web.config).

```xml
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <remove fileExtension=".7z" />
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".7z" mimeType="application/x-7z-compressed" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Allowing all types you need helped me in the past, too. Hope it helps you, too.

Here you can find a list with popular MIME types you can use:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types